# django startproject creating app as well

Tags: django

i dont remember this from 1.3 and i cant find it in the docs.

startproject appears to create both a project and an app underneath it. they've both got the same name.

```
python ./bin/django-admin.py startproject webapp
```

creates

```
/webapp/manage.py
```

and

```
/webapp/webapp/settings.py and others
```

anyone know why or link me to the page of the docco that explains this new behaviour? just skim read through the release notes and can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying out 1.4b1.

This is infact the new project layout.  It is mentioned in the release notes and they can explain it better than I can :).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4-beta-1/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

It's not actually an app but more about tidying of default files. As such it is not in INSTALLED_APPS and will not be processed in the same way as an app. This is a trap I fell into when my custom templatetags weren't being picked up.

Answer (score 2):

It's not creating an app. The directory inside is your project. The outside container is just a wrapper. `manage.py` has been move outside the scope of the project. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

Comment: no offence, but i voted for the one below as it had a nice description i instantly understood. not that yours didnt.